# Add a shortcut to change state to TODO and SCHEDULE entry for today

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to try a new approach to my org-mode and schedule tasks for today every morning. I usually set them to TODO only, but scheduling would also allow me to see how much I procrastinate some of them.

Is there a way to bind those two, so assign a shortcut to switch to TODO and assign SCHEDULED for todays date? Doing this manually is a bit too tedious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind function

```
(defun my-org-switch-to-todo-and-schedule-for-today ()
  "Set subtree TODO and schedule for today."
  (interactive)
  (unless (org-before-first-heading-p)
    (org-todo "TODO")
    (org-schedule nil "+0d")))
```

to a key of your choice.

The same functionality can be triggerd from the agenda with function

```
(defun my-org-agenda-switch-to-todo-and-schedule-for-today ()
  "Set item as TODO and schedule for today via agenda."
  (interactive)
  (when (eq major-mode 'org-agenda-mode)
    (org-agenda-todo "TODO")
    (org-agenda-schedule nil "+0d")))
```

Comment: This works great, but seems not to work when I'm in agenda mode. I didn't mention that, but thats how I would actually want to use this. I'll mark entries from my NEXT list to my TODAY list this way.

Comment: Please check out the other function which has been added in the answer section.

Comment: When I try the other function from agenda view I get message "Before first headline at position 7895 in buffer *Org Agenda*" and nothing else happens.

Comment: The proposed my-org-agenda-switch-to-todo-and-schedule-for-today does its job on my machine.  Please check if you copied the function correctly. In particular note the use of "org-agenda-todo" instead of "org-todo". (The latter has been used in the first function.)

Comment: My bad, I modifed the first entry instead of copying the new one making the mistake you mentioned in comment :) now it works, thanks a lot!